# What controls line editing boundaries when editing in bash

Tags: bash, tty, prompt

Was reading this wonderful article on [how tty works in Linux](https://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/index.php) and now wondering.

When running bash each line starts with a prompt and the user cannot erase the prompt.
Is this controlled by tty at the line discipline level or by bash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Bash itself, through the [Readline library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Readline). (Which is maintained by the Bash maintainer.) It knows where the input area starts, and acts accordingly.

The article you linked even mentions Readline and shells:

> So as a convenience, the operating system provides an editing buffer and some rudimentary editing commands [...]
> Advanced applications may disable these features by putting the line discipline in raw mode instead of the default cooked (or canonical) mode. Most interactive applications (editors, mail user agents, **shells**, all programs relying on curses or **readline**) run in raw mode, and handle all the line editing commands themselves.

(Though I wouldn't put curses and readline on the same level as editors, MUAs and shells. Rather, they're tools those programs use for handling input.)

On the other hand, even the built-in line editing doesn't let you overwrite what was previously on the screen. Try e.g. `echo -n 'prompt: '; cat`, you shouldn't be able to edit into the `prompt:`  part.

Comment: I wonder how it's handled at the line discipline level in your example, everything that the application printed is not editable and what is echoed from the user input is editable until submitted (return is hit)?

Comment: @axk, I think the terminal driver just keeps track of how many characters the user has input and allows for that many to be backspaced. Of course that can still mess up if the application prints something while the user is typing, e.g. something like  `(echo -n 'prompt: '; sleep 5; echo -n xyz) & cat` lets you type `abc`, then when the `xyz` appears, you can erase that, leaving the `abc` visible, but nothing actually in the input buffer